# How can I write this C dereferencing more succinctly?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I have a function that parses an input file into separate pages. other_func adds the lines to these pages. This is a simplified version of the function.

```
void func(FILE* f, page** p_pages, int* page_count) {

  ... do stuff, before passing a line struct and the current page to another function.

  page* p = *p_pages;
  int n = *page_count - 1;
  other_func(line, &p[n]);
}
```

In these last three lines I am trying to pass the address of the current page. I thought I could do this using something like `&*p_pages[page_count - 1]` but I can't seem to get it to work (getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error I think...).

Is there a shorter way to write those 3 lines?

---

EDIT: Adding more of the actual code.

```
/* struct declarations */

typedef struct page page;
typedef struct line line;

struct page {
  char*   title;
  char*   filename;
  page*   parent;
  line*   lines;
  int     numlines;
};

struct line {
  char  type;
  char* text;
};

/* relevant functions */

void addLineToPage(line l, page* p) {
  p->numlines++;
  p->lines = realloc(p->lines, sizeof(line) * p->numlines);
  p->lines[p->numlines - 1] = l;
}

void parse_file(FILE* file, page** p_pages, int* page_count) {
  char* rawline = 0;

  while( (rawline = p_getline(file)) ) {
    char rune = 0;
    int  n;
    sscanf(rawline, "%c %n", &rune, &n);
    remove_char(rawline, '\n');
    char* text = rawline + n;

    if (rune == '\n') {
      continue;
    } else if (!strchr(PI_RUNES, rune)) {
      *page_count = *page_count + 1;
      *p_pages = realloc(*p_pages, sizeof(page) * *page_count);

      int len = (int) strlen(rawline) + 1;
      char* fn = (char*) malloc(len * sizeof(char));
      string_to_filename(rawline, fn);
      page* p = *p_pages;
      int address = *page_count - 1;
      p[address] = (page) { .title = rawline, .filename = fn, .parent = NULL, .lines = NULL, .numlines = 0 };
    } else {
      line l = { .type = rune, .text = text };
      addLineToPage(l, *p_pages + *page_count - 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You want `&(*p_pages)[*page_count - 1]`.  The parentheses are needed, and you need to dereference `page_count`.

Comment: can you post the declaration of the type `page` and `other func` and how are you calling `func` in other words [**minimal-reproducible-example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @TomKarzes: or he could just do `other_func(line, *p_pages + *page_count - 1)`

Comment: @alk Yes, `*p_pages + *page_count - 1` is equivalent.

Comment: Tested with both - thank you. If you want to post as an answer I can mark it accepted.

@SaymoinSam do you still want me to post declarations? My question was about how to express something differently rather than debug code.

Comment: Just leave it as is. It's perfect this way. There is absolutely no need whatsoever to cram as much action as possible into one line. (Well not really perfect. What would be perfect is **returning a value** from your function. `realloc` doesn't accept no stinkin' double pointers, and that's no accident.)

Comment: @SaymoinSam I have only just started learning C, this is the first thing I've written (static site generator), so I will take all the criticism and help I can't get. Have updated the post.

Comment: Aside: Suggest `int  n = 0;` to help cope with the pathological case of `rawline` beginning with a read _null character_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `&(*p_pages)[*page_count - 1]` or, as alk points out, the equivalent `*p_pages + *page_count - 1`.

You can derive this as follows:  `p` is `*p_pages` and `n` is `*page_count - 1`, so by direct substitution `&p[n]` is `&(*p_pages)[*page_count - 1]`.

Using the fact that `a[b]` is `*(a + b)`, this can be transformed to `&*(*p_pages + *page_count - 1)`, which is just `*p_pages + *page_count - 1`.

Note that there is nothing wrong with splitting it up, as you originally had, but this shows how to express it as a single expression.

Comment: Appreciate the extra explanation you added, thank you.